# Diagonalizing a block matrix or decompose equation into two equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, diagonalization, block-matrices

Suppose the matrices $A$ and $B$ are $M \times N$; $X_1$ and $X_2$ are $N \times 1$; $G_1$ and $G_2$ are $M \times 1$

Then I hope to convert the equation

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
A&B\\B&A
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
X_1\\X_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
G_1\\G_2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
$$
to the form for applying the specific algorithm later
$$
\begin{align}
C_1 X_1 &= D_1\\
C_2 X_2 &= D_2
\end{align}
$$

Due to some properties of $A$ and $B$, the first equation can be rewritten into
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{A}&\hat{A}\\\hat{B}&-\hat{B}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
X_1\\X_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{G}_1\\\hat{G}_2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
$$
Any of the two converted into the second form can be accepted, is this possible?

ps1:

The left matrix of the first equation is below
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
J_1(kr)/r& k J_1'(kr) \\k J_1'(kr)&J_1(kr)/r
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
X_1\\X_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
G_1\\G_2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
$$

The problem is to find two matrices $D_1$ and $D_2$ that satisfies
$$
D_1 J_1(kr)/r + D_2 kJ_1'(kr) = 0
$$
Maybe this involves some properties of Bessel function.

It can be rewritten in further:
find function $x_1(r)$ and $x_2(r)$ that satisfies
$$
\int k J_1'(kr) x_1(r)dr + \int J_1(kr) / r x_2(r)dr = 0
$$